# Scifi book involving a main character is traveling between worlds with a giant, blind cat

Tags: story-identification, books, space

The book I'm looking for is probably '80s or '90s. The main character (MC) is traveling between worlds with a giant, immature, blind cat from a planet he was on. On that planet, hunters go out and look for the cats and have about a 50% chance of getting a cat before a cat gets them. When the hunters improve their gear to vastly improve their odds, the cats vanish and can't be found. Now, people want the MC's cat for various reasons.

Thanks for help identifying.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this, and do you recall anything about the cover?

Answer (score 12):

This could be James H. Schmitz' story ["Novice"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?55488), which was later incorporated into a novel, *The Universe against Her*. In "Novice", a young woman, Telzey Amberdon, has a large, immature alien "cat" as a pet. (However, it is not blind.) It turns out that the cats are as intelligent as human beings, and relished the opportunity to vie with hunters as long as the kills were evenly balanced. When men started to use advanced technology to hunt with, the cats disappeared, only to reappear, threateningly, in the humans' city. The cats are also telepathic, and when Telzey acts as an intermediary between the two species, she acquires the ability to read and influence minds. The story was originally published in [1962](https://gutenberg.org/ebooks/30458) but has been reprinted many times.

Comment: This sounds correct, and I doubt there's another book that follows this plot so closely. The 2000 "Telzey Amberdon" collection by Baen looks familiar as well. My memory though has the cat unable to reach maturity, and open its eyes, only if it returns to its home planet. I'll have to get a copy and re-read it to make sure. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Random available for free from Project Gutenberg: https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/30458

Comment: @Random If you're sure this answer is correct, you can accept it by clicking the checkmark on the left.

Comment: Did the human hunters resort to shooting platforms (maybe mid-air?) and long range rifles?  Did the proof that her "cat" was not the only remaining one involve many other "cats" appearing within the room, intimidating the officials?  I don't remember that novel, but I definitely remember the scenes (maybe I read the short story).

Comment: @MichaelRichardson - the intimidation part is definitely part of Novice. I don't remember the platforms/long-range rifles.

Comment: @MichaelRichardson Yes on all counts, except that the "platforms" are aircars:

"I don't really. But the crest cats seem to have felt the same way—at first. They were getting around one hunter for every cat that got shot. Humans were the most exciting game they'd ever run into.

"But then that ended, and the humans started knocking them out with stunguns from aircars where they couldn't be got at, and hauling them off while they were helpless. After it had gone on for a while, they decided to keep out of sight.